# The tuple representation of an integer

Tags: python, tuples

I am doing my CS homework and the question is:

```
n_to_tuple
    Args:
      n (int): an integer.
    Returns:
      t (tuple): tuple representation of the integer.
                 None if integer cannot be represented.
```

and it should return something like this:

```
>>> n_to_tuple(2)
((), ((),))
>>> n_to_tuple(0)
()
>>> n_to_tuple(1)
((),)
```

I've attempted this multiple times and I'm stuck on the formation of the tuple.

My attempts have included things like:

```
def tuple_to_n(t):
    lst = list(t)
    print(lst)
    count = 0
    for x in lst:
        print(x)
        if(x == "()"):
            count += 1

    if(count == 0):
        return -1
    else:
        return count
```

But this is to no avail as the tuple shall be represented like set theory
`((), ((),))`.

Comment: "I've attempted this multiple times" Well then include your attempts so we can help you with them.

Comment: Your attempts and expected output would be help if you can [edit] your post to include those. I'm not sure what a tuple representation of integer is supposed to be?

Comment: Please also provide more exhaustive instructions. Deducing it from a single example is dubious.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
def n_to_tuple(n):
    if n < 0: return None
    if n == 0: return ()
    t = list(n_to_tuple(n-1))
    t.append(tuple(t))
    return tuple(t)

for n in range(-2, 5):
    print(n, n_to_tuple(n))
```

Here is the result:

```
-2 None
-1 None
0 ()
1 ((),)
2 ((), ((),))
3 ((), ((),), ((), ((),)))
4 ((), ((),), ((), ((),)), ((), ((),), ((), ((),))))
```

The set representation S(n) of a nonnegative integer n is defined recursively as follows:

```
S(0) = {}
S(n+1) = S(n) union {S(n)}
```

For instance, we have

```
S(0) = {}
S(1) = S(0) union {S(n)} = {} union {{}} = {{}}
S(2) = S(1) union {S(1)} = {{}} union {{{}}} = {{}, {{}}}
```

Since there cannot be a set of sets in Python, the problem asks for the tuple version T(n) of S(n). For instance,

```
T(0) = ()
T(1) = ((),)
T(2) = ((), ((),))
```

It is a bit tricky, since tuples are immutable.
Things would be slightly easier if asking for the list representation of the nonnegative integer n:

```
def n_to_list(n):
    if n < 0: return None
    if n == 0: return []
    l = n_to_list(n-1)
    l.append(l.copy())
    return l

for n in range(-2, 5):
    print(n, n_to_list(n))
```

Here is the result:

```
-2 None
-1 None
0 []
1 [[]]
2 [[], [[]]]
3 [[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]
4 [[], [[]], [[], [[]]], [[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]]
```

Comment: Some explanations would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to produce a tuple of length `n` where each element is itself an empty tuple, you can do:

```
tuple(() for _ in range(n))
```

Replace the `()` with whatever else you might want the tuple elements to be.

If the idea is to have the tuples be increasingly nested, that's likely to be easiest with a recursive solution:

```
>>> def n_to_tuple(n):
...     if n == 0:
...         return ()
...     return (n_to_tuple(n-1),)
...
>>> n_to_tuple(0)
()
>>> n_to_tuple(1)
((),)
>>> n_to_tuple(2)
(((),),)
```

This doesn't match your expected output for `n=2` though so I'm not sure exactly what the relationship is supposed to be.

(edit) with the clarification, the solution is actually just a combination of the above two:

```
>>> def n_to_tuple(n):
...     if n == 0:
...         return ()
...     return tuple(n_to_tuple(i) for i in range(n))
...
>>> n_to_tuple(0)
()
>>> n_to_tuple(1)
((),)
>>> n_to_tuple(2)
((), ((),))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply; I basically want to make a tuple that takes n and returns something like this; https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/2a3fd1c1a3c8623cea7e68dbf7f10bd99cf4ea50

Comment: Ah, that's a little bit more like a Fibonacci series, in that each element is defined recursively from *multiple* prior elements.  Did the recursive function I provided give you enough of a start to be able to make it work for the larger values of `n`?  It'll probably end up looking like a combination of the two different snippets I provided.  :)

Comment: @Kyle: What wikipedia article is that illustration from?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers

Answer (score 0):

Use unpacking with a recursive solution:

```py
def n_to_tuple(n):
    if n == 0:
        return ()
    previous = n_to_tuple(n - 1)
    return (*previous, previous)
```